# "Burned in" pixels on TFT monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, x-server, tft

If an image is displayed long enough on my TFT screen, a "shadow" of it is still visible like a semitransparent overlay for some time. The longer it is shown, and the brighter the image, the longer the "burned in" image stays. This is under Linux. What is the cause if this?

- Could it be that the monitor is running at a non-native frequency (Hz)?
- If not, any other theories as to what could be the cause?
- How do I check which frequency my monitor is running?
- How do I change the frequency?

If it matters, I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 but the relevant settings are probably in some settings file of the X server.

Also, bonus points to anyone that knows if this phenomena has a name, would make it easier to search for info.

Comment: @joe read the FAQ: http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: Thanks for info @John . I agree that its acceptable question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LCD Image Persistence](http://compreviews.about.com/od/monitors/a/LCDBurnIn.htm)

Comment: Added a screensaver thats activated after 8 minutes, and the screen is deactivated after 15 minutes. Lets see if this helps. But I take that this "image persistence" is something you just have to live with if you opt for a lcd monitor?

Answer (score 1):

I just happens to some LCD monitors sometimes. I have a monitor that if you leave a webpage open for too long, the title bar will start to discolor the screen when it's removed.

I've found that leaving a solid black or solid white image on the screen overnight generally fixes the problem.

I would just turn down the brightness (for less power consumption and monitor longevity, the backlight has nothing to do with the 'burn in') and leave a screen saver on overnight. On my monitor, once the screen is back to normal, it doesn't come back for a while.