# Are there tools to reduce or eliminate LCD Image Persistence?

Tags: display, tft, persistence

As with the asker of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/19102/16858) I have a monitor which suffers from terrible [LCD Image Persistence](http://compreviews.about.com/od/monitors/a/LCDBurnIn.htm) problems. After a few hours, static elements on screen start to persist and in some areas of the screen (particularly at the top, where VMware Workstation positions tabs for switching VMs) I get brighter pixels bleeding up into darker areas.

The screen is a pretty old TFT screen which was very cheap when new, but is otherwise functioning fine, so I don't want to replace it quite yet.

Things I have tried so far:

- Leaving the screen on over night, with a blank screen screen saver.
- Leaving the screen on over night, with a screen saver that constantly rotates new patterns.
- Otherwise, I always turn the monitor off when not in use, but often the discolouration is visible first thing in the morning after having been switched off over night.

None of these things have helped with this monitor.

I do wonder, however, if anyone has come across a screen saver *optimised* for recovering badly image persisted screens. Perhaps by cycling through black/red/green/blue/white colour cycle patterns designed to *free-up* permanently imprinted crystals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the blank (all white) screen saver. Turn your brightness up. Unless you want to buy an expensive application that does little more thats about the best you can do

Comment: It's interesting that an all white screen does seem to bleed away the imprint, whereas an all black screen doesn't. Unfortunately, while a few hours of white screen does seem to clear the persistence, it comes back just as quickly. I will have to experiment more.